# Locator not respecting exclude

Tags: javascript, protractor

I expect the selector

```
element(by.css('html:not([data-spellcheck="false"])'))
// or
element(by.css('*:not([data-spellcheck="false"])'))
```

to return any element without the data attribute `data-spellcheck="false"`, but it doesn’t work. How should I change it?

Comment: The first one will only select `html` element or nothing (maybe you meant `html :not(/*...*/)`). The second one should work (but `*` is not required).

Comment: Error `WARNING - more than one element found for locator By.cssSelector("html :not([data-spellcheck=\"false\"]") - the first result will be used`

Comment: Error `WARNING - more than one element found for locator By.cssSelector(":not([data-spellcheck=\"false\"]") - the first result will be used`

Comment: It works with those warnings, but it isn’t filtering the result as desired. The only thing that partially worked was `div:not([data-spellcheck="false"])`, but I want it to be more flexible and inclusive than that

Comment: Can you paste the html and what the locator returns? i.e. what do you mean by "it doesn't work": does the locator return elements with the excluded data attribute?

Comment: Too complicated. Assume a surrounding element of `html` and the ability for `data-spellcheck="false"` to exist on any element.

Comment: @hankduan `html:not([data-spellcheck="false"])` selects all text when using `.getText()` even when some items have `data-spellcheck="false"` on them

Comment: I think the problem could be the text selection as it won’t remove child text

Comment: If i'm understanding you properly, you want the selector to return you the html, but with all elements with 'data-spellcheck=false' removed? That's not what a selector would do. So given html:
    <html>
    <div id="A">
    <p id="B">1</p>
    <p id="C" data-spellcheck="false">2</p>
    </div>
    </html>

`:not([data-spellcheck="false"])` would return you two elements: id='A' and all subbranches, and id=B. It's not going to return you just the id='A' div element, with id=C branch removed.
so element.all(by.css(':not([data-spellcheck="false"])).getText() would return ["12", "1"]

Comment: Thanks! I used `element.all(by.css(':not([data-spellcheck="false"])'))` as recommended, but unfortunately it is still grabbing children of a div with `data-spellcheck="false"`. You can see the offending portion here https://gist.github.com/kirkstrobeck/5ab5d91dba7933151b25

Comment: Sorry, can you provide a more complete example. I'm still not really sure what is happening. (or what that gist you provided is supposed to mean). Here, given this html snippet https://gist.github.com/hankduan/416433e0504e2d428af8, what are you expecting `element.all(by.css(':not([data-spellcheck="false"])')).getOuterHtml()` to return, and what is it returning? (I'm expecting two elements: '<span id="id2">A</span>B<div id="id3"><div id="id4" data-spellcheck="false">C</div></div>' AND
'<div id="id3"><div id="id4" data-spellcheck="false">C</div></div>'. Is that not what you're seeing)